# Start random activity

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent, android-activity

Is it possible to start a random activity if e.g. a button is clicked?

I already saw some solutions with switch/case, but I dont really want to do something like this:

```
case 1: startintent1;
break; 
case 2: startintent2;
break; 
...
case 100: startintent100;
break;
```

Is it maybe possible to store the code that is used to open an activity in an array and then pick an item from that array with `Random`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean "is clicked" or "isn't clicked"?

Comment: I sort of don't understand what you're asking. Do you want to take an array that you have in one activity and use it in another activity? If so you want to add the array as an extra to the intent. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: No, I just want to start a random activity if I click a button, I don't want to open a specific, predefined activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array of classes like this:

```
Class<?>[] classes = new Class<?>[] { MainActivity.class, DatabaseActivity.class };
```

Or use an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
classes.add(MainActivity.class);
```

then use your random number as the index.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), classes[randomNumber];
or
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), classes.get(randomNumber);

startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what's wrong with using a switch case, but I guess you could put your Activities in an array and then use a random integer 0 to n to pick one.

Comment: 100 item switch case is bad code style. Not object oriented and more lines of code then a list / array based approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
Class c = Class.forName("classname");
Method m = c.getMethod("startintent"+i);
m.invoke(this);
```

This will invoke by name. If all your functions are all consistently named. Then use random to append a number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

x.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
private static final Random random = new Random();

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 //TODO --place your activity in an array list here 
    int randomMsgIndex = random.nextInt(yourarraylist.length - 1);
//TODO-start that activity using intents.
}
```

});